# Is this proof that $\lfloor x \rfloor \geq n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-verification, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In this text the fractional part of a real $x$ shall be denoted $\{x\}$, such that $x = \lfloor x \rfloor + \{x\}$.

**Theorem**:

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1} : \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \geq n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor $$

**Proof**:

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $x$ be a nonnegative real number.

$$ x = n \frac{x}{n} = n \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor + \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\} \right) $$

Keeping in mind that the floor function is increasing:

$$ \lfloor x \rfloor = \left\lfloor n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor + n \left\{\frac{x}{n}\right\} \right\rfloor \geq \left\lfloor n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor \right\rfloor = n \left\lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right\rfloor $$

$$\square$$

Having just written it down it seems so clear (and unexpectedly short), but is this proof correct? What could be improved about it?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: It is ok. Why do you say it is unexpectedly short?

Comment: @Crostul I suppose it has something to do with the theorem holding true only for integer $n$, a constraint I did not notice earlier. I am very new to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A shorter proof would note that we always have $y \ge \lfloor y \rfloor$, hence ${x \over n} \ge \lfloor {x \over n} \rfloor$. Multiplying by $n$ gives
$x \ge n\lfloor {x \over n} \rfloor$. Taking the floor of both sides gives the desired result (noting that the floor of an integer is the integer).

Comment: Thank you. Your last sentence, although noted in my proof, I had not realised until the end.

Comment: Floors & ceilings can be confusing.

Comment: (I was actually serious when I wrote the previous comment, it has nothing to do with alcohol consumption.)